# hello i was creating a bot using python which will go to the given link and click follow to the followers

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to get hold of the element

[image]
[image]
[image]

It worked pretty much good.but i am unable to get hold the follow button and click it. I used xpath,class,css selectors but it didnt work.When i used tagname i was able to get hold of the element but iam unable to click it.It gives me an error

when xpath is used
[image]

when class name is used
[image]